# Add image on top of bottomsheet in Android

Tags: android

How can add image on top of the bottom sheet in Android? [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBj3r.png)

I tried this but it doesn't work. I want the transparency as shown in the image attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/myBottomLL"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myBottomLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow these links. 
How to make the background transparent:
https://medium.com/@manuaravindpta/transparent-background-for-bottomsheetdialog-396a1a646f1b

How to make the bottom sheet full screen:
https://medium.com/better-programming/bottom-sheet-android-340703e114d2

For the circular image view:
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Just add a transparent View to the top like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/topImage"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_circle_background_color="@android:color/white" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/transparentRegion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                    android:tint="@android:color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/other_content_goes_here"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Other Content"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/extraSpace"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="800dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Set the theme of the BottomSheetDialogFragment.
You can also add a BottomSheetCallback and decrease the height of the transparent space at the top as you scroll up